# Converting channel images to vanilla file field type

Tags: file-uploads, channel-images, files

I am trying to convert the channel images module into a plain old vanilla file field type. Specifically for the reason that the folder structure channell images imposes (entry id for each folder, images tucked in) and the multiple relationships in the database make for problems when I am trying to call this from specifically Open API.

So to that end, has anyone done a conversion like this? Am I right in assuming that I will have to do a ton of scripting to make this happen? The process I was going to follow was as:

1. Copy/Move all images to the main uploads folder as defined in my upload prefs
2. Look up all the channel images in my DB by a big nasty dirty sql query, take the file name and copy this (again via a big dirty update query) and copy {filedir_4}/filename.jpg into the new vanilla file field
3. Change all my templates to remove the channel images tags for my image call

Just wondering if someone has done this and should I watch out for anything in particular.